Link2SD - Game ignores binded data after link
I use Link2SD Plus mostly to link app data from my internal storage to my external memory, I don't do anything fancy like creating a second partition to link obb, I simply link the game DATA FOLDER (where applicable) to my SD card on the first partition.
Now here's the issue, I recently flashed my device clean and upgraded from Android 11 to 12, I usually play my big games with the game files linked to my sd, I downloaded and installed the game files on my internal storage, I linked the data folder to my SD card, I launch the game and everything should be up and running but instead, it starts downloading the game's data all over again. Normally, this never happens unless I forget to bind the data folders stored on my SD card.
I tried linking the base game and then installing the data, but that didn't work, I'm at a loss for what to do. I tried downgrading to Android 11 but Link2sd just isn't working the way it used to. Is there another/better way to achieve the same goal? I'm looking at Fbind but I have no idea how to use it, I'd appreciate a simple cmd line I can run
Redmi Note 9 Pro (joyeuse) rooted with magisk
